# Why /logout calling throws "Method not allowed"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

My app using Spring Session *(with Redis)*. And i use custom login controller, because i use external React client, not default Spring login page.

Login controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/login", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String login(@RequestBody LoginDataTo loginData) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            loginData.getEmail(),
            loginData.getPassword());
    Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

    SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .setAuthentication(authentication);

    return "OK";
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable() // login form is disable, because i use external React client
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable();

    http
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/logout").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

So... The `/login` endpoint's work is correct. But `/logout` endpoint work is incorrect. When calling `/logout`, it returns json:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-30T13:45:09.142+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

Here is the request, which i using in Postman:
`GET http://localhost:8080/logout`

Cookie and session are deleted, that is logout's work is correct, but why is it returning this json?

Comment: @Zhenyria By default logout redirects to the login page. This redirect is a `GET` request, but your login controller has no mapping for `GET`. That's the reason for your problem. To solve it, add a mapping to your controller for `GET` or change the default redirect (as you did in your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by means of `logoutSuccessHandler` setting:

```
http
    .logout()
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));
```

Now `/logout` calling returns **200 OK**.